# What does "no upvoted answers" really mean on the Unanswered Questions page?

Tags: feature-request, support, unanswered-questions, question-count

When visiting the unanswered page (e.g. [stackoverflow.com/unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered)), I find the listed number of questions to be confusing.

[image]

The "no upvoted answers" language isn't clear. Does this include questions which have...

- Accepted answers with no votes? (I presume not)
- Answers with only downvotes? (I presume so)
- Answers with upvotes but also at least that many downvotes? (I.e. upvoted and net score <= 0)

Once this is clarified, I also think it would be nice to update the page's text, assuming something appropriately succinct can be thought up. For example, if #3 above is true, change the text to something along the lines of "questions with zero score answers".

Please note this has nothing to do with the unanswered tab on the questions list.